# Is it ok to provide link-only answers on duplicate questions that are not closed as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

It seems like there is a hesitancy here to close questions as duplicates. I don't know if people are after more reputation or do not want to scare off newcomers, but it seems like even questions that are exact duplicates are viewed and commented upon by many experienced users without a single close vote.

For instance, [Fridge tripping GFCI Outlet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/217823/36011) got 3 up-votes after it got a few "close as duplicate" votes in reference to [Why would a GFCI trip on refrigerator circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/53252/36011) (and this is as close to a duplicate question that I have ever seen where the original question is also better written and more thoroughly researched). While it is a well-written question from a new user, it just seems weird to me to reward a user for not searching for existing answers to an identical question before asking for help.

Many experienced users posted comments, but none posted answers even though I know more than a few regular names who posted comments that would jump at answering this type of question. It makes me think that they are not marking it as a duplicate, but also deciding not to answer because they know it is a duplicate.

After another answer was accepted yesterday which more-or-less was interpreted by the asker to disregard GFCI for a fridge in a garage. I went ahead and posted a basically link-only answer (https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/218108/36011) to the new question in reference to Tester101's excellent response to the original question in hopes of:

1. Provide a direct reference to what I still think is the best answer to the question.
2. Raise awareness of that the question is a duplicate in hopes of it being closed/merged.

While this does not solve the root of the "close as duplicate" dilema (I know I have seen other questions fall into the same pattern in the past), is this a reasonable stop-gap or is the type of answer I posted also discouraged?

Comment: Maybe part of the problem is that (at least in my experience) searching for the duplicate which you *know exists* can be an exercise in frustration... I Find SE's search function to be very broken...